# How do I store a boolean test/expression without Evaluating it?

Tags: java, boolean, boolean-expression

So I'd like to be able to store a `boolean` test without storing the value (`true`/`false`), I'd like to be able to pass multiple of these `boolean` tests through methods. Possibly even switching arguments and operators. Is there anyway to do this?

I've seen some people save them as `String`s then use `Interpreter` from BeanShell, but is there another way? Or should I try my best at creating a way to do this?

Comment: please give an example of what you are trying to acheive

Comment: You can't "store" an expression without evaluating it in Java, but you can execute a method (or a lambda) to evaluate an expression later.

Comment: First let start with terminology: `true` or `false` are the **only** values `boolean` expresions can have. What you're talking about is saving a text representation of logical conditions.

Comment: "_store a boolean test without storing the value_" Not sure what you mean by this.

Comment: Lambda looks like what I want, thanks guys. @Takendarkk I just meant passing the `("happy" == "good")` part without passing a `true` or `false` value. I realized a little while ago I basically wanted to pass the function, and I realize this was kind of a stupid question. thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 8, you can use a lambda.  [`java.util.function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) has a number of classes that represent functions that return booleans (`Predicate`, `BiPredicate`, `IntPredicate`, `DoublePredicate`, etc.), and those types can be used to hold an expression that returns a boolean.  Example:

```
BiPredicate<Integer,Integer> pred = (x, y) -> x > y;
```

Now `pred` contains a function that tests whether the first integer is greater, but that function isn't actually evaluated until you use something like

```
boolean result = pred.test(arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: Thanks! Lambda looks like what I want!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function to store an expression for future use. For example:

```
class GreaterThanTester implements Callable<Boolean> {

    private int a;
    private int b;

    public GreaterThanTester(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() {
        return (a > b);
    }
}
```

Then, you can store the expression like this:

```
Callable<Boolean> storedTester = new GreaterThanTester(10, 20);
```

Then at evaluation time:

```
Boolean result = storedTester.call();
```

You can create many different types of `Tester`s like this and store them all as `Callable<Boolean>`.